# How to find whether df column name contains substring in Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

My df has multiple columns. I want to check whether one column name contains a substring. Such as % in SQL.

I try to use this one but seems not to work. I don't want to give a full name to find whether that column exists.

If I can find this column, I also want to rename the column using `.withColumnRename`
Such like

```
if (df.columns.contains("%ABC%" or "%BCD%")) df.withColumnrename("%ABC%" or "%BCD%","ABC123") else println(0)
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59065137/select-columns-in-spark-dataframe-based-on-column-name-pattern

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this.

- The filter can help you select you columns which need to update.
- Write your update logic in the `flodLeft()()` method.

`flodLeft` is a useful method in scala. If you want to learn more about flodLeft , you can search `scala foldLeft example` in google.

So, good luck with you.

```scala
df.schema.fieldNames.map(_.toUpperCase).filter(x => !x.contains("")).foldLeft(df)((a,b) => {
      a.withColumnRenamed(b, ("abc_" + b).toLowerCase() )
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

First, find a column that matches your criteria:

```scala
df.columns
  .filter(c => c.contains("ABC") || c.contains("BCD"))
  .take(1)
```

This will either return an empty `Array[String]` if no such column exists or an array with a single element if the column does exist. `take(1)` is there to make sure that you won't be renaming more than one column using the same new name.

Continuing the previous expression, renaming the column boils down to calling `foldLeft`, which iterates over the collection chaining its second argument to the "zero" (`df` in this case):

```scala
  .foldLeft(df)((ds, c) => ds.withColumnRenamed(c, "ABC123"))
```

If the array was empty, nothing will get called and the result will be the original `df`.

Here it is in action:

```
df.printSchema
// root
// |-- AB: integer (nullable = false)
// |-- ABCD: string (nullable = true)

df.columns
  .filter(c => c.contains("ABC") || c.contains("BCD"))
  .take(1)
  .foldLeft(df)(_.withColumnRenamed(_, "ABC123"))
  .printSchema
// root
// |-- AB: integer (nullable = false)
// |-- ABC123: string (nullable = true)
```